# New to Angular JS - Not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to execute a very simple program to return addition of 2 numbers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
First Name: <input type="number" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="number" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + lastName}}
</body>
</html>
```

This code is working in one of the tutorial site, but when I try to run in my machine, it displays {{firstName + lastName}}. Do I need to download any specific jar or lib before coding angular?

Comment: `firstName` and `lastName` inputs with `type="number"` ?

Answer (score 2):

`myApp` module is not defined in your code. You need to define or just remove it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
  First Name:
  <input type="number" ng-model="firstName">
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="number" ng-model="lastName">
  <br>
  <br>Full Name: {{firstName + lastName}}
</body>

</html>
```

or define module using **[`angular.module('myApp', []);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)**

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  First Name:
  <input type="number" ng-model="firstName">
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="number" ng-model="lastName">
  <br>
  <br>Full Name: {{firstName + lastName}}
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

First, remove `myApp`:

```
<body ng-app>
```

Second, include the file that has `myApp` defined inside:

```
  <script src="myApp.js"></script>
```

and your `myApp` should look something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [function()...])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pranav C Balan's answer is correct but I would like to add that the inputs should be set to type="text".

```
<input type="number" ng-model="firstName">
```

should be:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
```

Or you won't see results if you type in letters into the number input.